# Operation on 2 entities - how and where to design?

Tags: c#, java, architecture

There are interfaces

```
interface Male {
  boolean likes(Female female);
}

interface Female {
  boolean likes(Male male);
}
```

There's also interface

```
interface GoodCouple {
  Male getMale();
  Female getFemale();
}
```

You're given 2 sets:

```
Iterable<Male> males = ...;
Iterable<Female> females = ...;
```

And you're asked to build the set of `GoodCouple`s:

```
Iterable<GoodCouple> couples = XXXXXXXXXXXX(males, females);
```

The question is, how would you define `XXXXXXXXXXXX`? It's not about algorithm, it's about architecture: what is `XXXXXXXXXXXX`? Is it some class' method? What name would you give to that class? What are responsibilities of this class?

If it matters, languages are either C# or Java.

Comment: Why ideas do *you* have?

Comment: off-topic: IMO, the design is too conservative :)

Comment: @Bala R - Hahahaha, made my day:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be part of a `GoodCoupleFactory`: `CreateGoodCouples(males, females)`

Answer (score 1):

```
class GoodCoupleDetectorImpl : GoodCoupleDetector {
    public Iterable<GoodCouple> findGoodCouples(Iterable<Male> males, Iterable<Female> females) { }
}
```

This way you can use different strategies for finding good couples.

Answer (score 0):

I would put methods like `XXXXXXXXXXXX` and all other methods not directly belonging to either `Male` or `Female` in a class like `MaleFemaleUtils` or `GoodCoupleUtils`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be a method in a class. I'd call it `MatchMaker` and the method `FindMatches` :)

Answer (score 0):

[**C# Linq Zip**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx)

```
IEnumerable<Male> males = ...;
IEnumerable<Female> females = ...;
IEnumerable<GoodCouples> couples = males.Zip(female, (male, female) => new GoodCouple { male = male, female = female });
```

Comment: it's not about zipping up all males and females to GoodCouples. it's about making GoodCouple instances from compatible males and females. The `likes()` method in the interfaces must be involved somehow, i think.